# Does drawing a dash across the numeral 7 (seven) increase legibility?

Tags: physical, font, typography, legibility

The RBRC battery recycling logo was recently updated to add a dash to the final digit 7 (seven) in the phone number:

[image: RBRC logo with dash in numeral 7]

Does this make the phone number more legible? In what situations, if any, is writing the numeral 7 with a dash appropriate? Bear in mind that the logo is often found on batteries, where the text may be very small and on a non-flat surface.

Comment: Although I like dashed 7's on handwritten things, personally I find the 7 a bit distracting in that font, and at firs I'm mentally trying to process whether that's an upside down british pounds symbol or a number or a symbol or... I would have used a 1 with bottom serifs rather than adding a dash to the 7 to make them more clearly "different"

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is a response to consumer complaints about the readability of the phone number. Not sure if this was the best solution...

Comment: They could also just route both phone numbers to the same call center.

Comment: If I don't look at the 7 on the right while looking at the 1 on the left I find it a little confusing to figure out it is a 1 and not a 7. I would consider adding an extra dash below the 1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is most prevalent with hand-written numbers as some people draw their 1's like their 7's. The dash is used the differentiate the two from each other.

With respect to this specific case, I assume it is for the same reason - because the number is along a curve the 7 could be interpreted as a 1, so the dash was added for **clarity**.

I don't think I have actually seen a non-'handwritten' typeface that has a 7 with a dash in it.

Another method is to add a serif (underline on the bottom) to 1's to differentiate it from 7's.

Comment: Since the 7 in this logo is rotated on its side, so it is easier to misinterpret it for a 1. A stroke across the 7 helps distinguish it from a 1. Another possible soution might be to make the logo more oval, so the 7 is not on its side, or to add the phone number below, etc.

Comment: Dashing handwritten 7's is also cultural: its the way that the French are taught to write "7" at school.

Comment: Just be careful not to strike your 7 too low or it might end up looking like a mis-serifed 1

Answer (score 1):

For most purposes, legibility of the "7" would be enhanced far more by adding a serif to the left side of the crossbar and emphasizing the curve on the downstroke, than by adding a dash through it.  There are a few rare situations where adding a dash might improve legibility, but they would generally involve things like markings on elastic surfaces.  In such contexts, putting a strong bar on the bottom of a "1" might result in its being mistaken for a "2", but a distorted "1" without a bar at the bottom might be mistaken for a distorted "7".  Adding a crossbar to the seven would yield a shape which, even distorted, would not resemble the distorted form of anything else.

Unless really severe distortion is expected, however, bending the down-stroke of the seven is probably a better approach than adding a dash.  Note that some fonts add a dash to the "Z" to distinguish it from "2", and adding a dash to the seven might cause it to resemble a "Z" whose bottom got cut off.